# Overlay differently based on click first

Tags: css, z-index

It's simple I guess:

I have two links: INFO and THUMBNAILS.
The first opens an info page over the body

```
{z-index:+1}
```

The second opens a page with miniatures (z-index:+1)

How can I code that when one of the two is open, if I click the other one it overlays?

http://jsfiddle.net/8g6bm1px/

Comment: What do you mean by `it overlays`? Can you provide your HTML and JS code?

Comment: Here's the JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/8g6bm1px/ @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
var hidden=$('.hidden');
var thumbnails=$('.thumbnails');
$('#thumb').click(function(){
    if(thumbnails.hasClass('visible')){
        thumbnails.removeClass('visible');
    }
    else{
        thumbnails.addClass('visible');
        hidden.removeClass('visible');
    }
});
$('#slid').click(function(){
    if(hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.removeClass('visible');
    }
    else{
        hidden.addClass('visible');
        thumbnails.removeClass('visible');
    }
});});
```

Here you go, code fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that the last opened link will be on top, probably the easiest way is to use jQuery and some class with higher z-index

css:

```
.last-opened {
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('last-opened');
    $(this).addClass('last-opened');
});
```

Your updated
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g6bm1px/2/)